# How to return the 3 minimum scores in SQL Linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a table name called Scores with column name (Total_Score) in SQL server. now my question is how to get the 3 manimum numbers using min function in Linq?.

```
Total_Score    Result Should be
-----------   -----------------
    23             21
    21             22
    25             23
    40         
    24         
    22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scores.OrderBy(c => c.Total_Score).Take(3);
```